# How can I replace the seal on the bottom of my shower door?

Tags: repair, shower

I am trying to replace the seal on the bottom of my shower door. Any ideas what it is called and/or what I could replace it with? The "Shower Door Company" of Atlanta, Georgia made the door, which is the "Cameo" model.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is a "replacement shower door gasket".  I found what appears to be an exact match for what you need here:

[Replacement gasket](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=replacement%20shower%20door%20gasket&hl=en&prmd=imvns&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&biw=1533&bih=828&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=2015647335081071625&sa=X&ei=9_KCTqfKLdPI0AGR0qWmAQ&ved=0CG8Q8gIwAQ)

Check the measurements against your own part to be sure.

Good luck!